# Any new technologies that are ready to be discovered?

Tags: computers, logic

As an electronics engineer, (sort of), I understand how transistor gates (AND, OR, NAND, NOR, XOR, etc.) are combined to create all of our digital devices.  The first computers were created in the mid-twentieth century.  However, the very first ones used simple telegraph relays as the switching device.  And yes, it is possible to create all of the necessary logic gates with relays.
With this in mind, why did it take nearly 100 years from the invention of the telegraph relay until these were combined to create an electric computer machine?  It seems that the technology was right there, under everyone's noses, waiting to be recognized and developed.  That is my first question.
The second question is regarding the same thought - are there any current technologies that we have now that may be used for much more complex and useful devices?  Something right under our noses.

Comment: I mean....a. If I had an amazing invention I wouldn't be sharing it with you and b. If I had an amazing invention, I'd be selling it to people not trolling around some internet community...

Comment: "are there any current technologies that we have now that may be used for much more complex and useful devices? Something right under our noses. "  If there were, we would have done it already.  Real life isn't like a videogame, you can't see what new technologies will be unlocked by the current one you're researching.

Comment: @Ryan_L actually, if we stopped all research right now and only focused on current technologies we had now, we could still be innovating for at least 4 decades. For example I designed a system for a blind man (3% of vision left) that helped him "see" when the turn began on an ice skating ring by simulating a sound to follow and triangulating his position on the track locally. A buddy designed a new wheelchair module to attach a cycling module that would put all the weight on the cycling module instead of making the wheelchair weigh 2 kilo's more when you want the option to connect the module.

Comment: Welcome to the site Baruch.  Interesting question, but not really on-topic for the site.  You query is part real world history (I bet articles exist on the first question) and part speculation.  Neither of which are tied to world building making this off topic.  The site is a little different from standard discussion forums, its all about specific questions getting specific answers.  Check out the [help] and [tour] and:  [How to ask](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
 provides good guidance on writing questions.

Comment: There are new diodes on the market that use quantum tunneling that enable them to be tuned to allow only certain frequencies to pass. They are currently used in guitar circuits to selectively impart effects on particular frequencies. Could they be applied to communication circuits? Encryption circuits? A new field just waiting to be developed.

Comment: To better meet the requirements for worldbuilding, perhaps you could specify an application and ask about potential technologies that could be applied to it. This would limit the scope.

Comment: (a) Most inventions are developed due to need.  Most of our modern computing is due to the need to quickly calculate ballistics and code breaking in WWII.  (b) If you think about this part of your question, anyone who could answer it would be running to the patent office, not telling the public here.

Comment: If you are interested, research the Attanasoff-Berry computer. The idea worked, but was abandoned. But it was the genius of Atanasoff who, on a paper napkin after a few beers and a long drive, posited the use of Boolean algebra (An until then curiosity in mathematics) be used for electronic computers. Without this insight, no successful digital age. For instance http://www4.ncsu.edu/~belail/The_Introduction_of_Electronic_Computing/Atanasoff-Berry_Computer.html

Answer (score 1):

https://theconversation.com/harder-than-diamond-stronger-than-steel-super-conductor-graphenes-unreal-5123
http://www.abc.net.au/news/science/2017-01-31/scientists-cook-up-super-strong-graphene-out-of-soybean-oil/8223686

Graphene, 200 times stronger than steel, 100 times as durable than diamond, I think twice as light as steel and its Very Conductive And also semiconductive. Been researching it for years.

It is truly going to change the world when we figure out how to mass produce it right now it can only be made in very small fractions. But people say indestructible cars, space elevators, super computers and it is the first 2 dimensional material which is 1 single atom thick. Which also leaves room for quantum computers.

Not to mention perfect water filters, could filter clean salt free water from the ocean, it could lead to better solar panels and electricity, mile high if not multi mile high skyscrapers or windmills.

Deeper drills, probably drilling deeper into the crust than ever before or even large underground facility's with the metal as super supports. That increased pressure could lead to better spaceships as well. The list goes on and on and on.

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/instead-of-filling-cavities-dentists-may-soon-regenerate-teeth1/

Teeth regeneration is suppose to happen literally before 2025 it was suppose to happen by 2018 back in 2012 and they've made very very great steps towards it but still a bit far away.

This could lead to many many other regenerative parts

Also check out this awesome website on new future tech and what not!
http://www.futuretimeline.net/latest.htm#.V-7o-SgrK70

Elon musk is looking to send the "Big fucking rocket" yes that is the real name, to mars, and colonize it.
https://www.wired.co.uk/article/elon-musk-bfr-big-rocket-earth-mars-spacex
They're working on a new material to remove Co2 carbon from the atmosphere.
https://www.ted.com/talks/jennifer_wilcox_a_new_way_to_remove_co2_from_the_atmosphere

The entire wheat genomes has been sequenced.
http://www.latimes.com/science/sciencenow/la-sci-sn-bread-wheat-genome-20180816-story.html
New AI Being used for eye doctors
https://www.futuretimeline.net/blog/2018/08/22.htm

Oh and one of my favorites, the superman crystal is becoming a real thing as well, it can store 356 TB for 13 billion years on quartz crystal! The size of just a quarter!
https://money.cnn.com/2016/02/17/technology/5d-data-storage-memory-crystals/index.html

Comment: I highly recommend futuretimeline.net. According to it, theres some crazy stuff about to go down.

Comment: It is less conductive then gold. The problem with graphene is it sits between being a conductor and being a semi conductor making it very hard to use.  However they have successfully doped graphene to Make it less conductive and created a very simple working chip.  I think at Cal tech? But am not positive.

Comment: Thanks @GarretGang I updated it, but somewhere i did read it was more conductive although it could of been speculation

Comment: Nanotubes are now conductive then gold. I think they created a room temperature super conductor about 10 nanometers long at MIT, but I might have the university wrong.

Answer (score -3):

To address your first question:

> There are two kinds of scientific progress: the methodical experimentation and categorization which gradually extend the boundaries of knowledge, and the revolutionary leap of genius which redefines and transcends those boundaries. Acknowledging our debt to the former, we yearn, nonetheless, for the latter.
>
> -- Academician Prokhor Zakharov, *Sid Meier's Alpha Centauri*

Predicting revolutionary, transcendent developments that redefine the way we live is fruitless. If they were predictable, they wouldn't be transcendent and they're almost certainly not revolutionary. What is predictable, however, are methodical improvements: what we have, we will make better, year by year. We have medicine; our medicines will grow more effective in a wider variety of cases. We have transportation; our transports will grow faster, safer, and more convenient. We have manufacturing; our processes will grow cheaper, more reliable, and more readily available.

Methodical experimentation has a lot going for it: it's easier, for one. You don't need to be as much of a transcendent genius, which is good for the 99.99% of us who aren't. It's cheaper and faster to see results, and those results will typically be useful in some way to people *right away*. Revolutionary leaps in understanding are harder, more demanding in terms of researchers, time, and money, and they often languish for a long time before their "killer app" arrives. Lasers, for instance, were not seen as useful when they were first developed; now they're a critical part of communications infrastructure.

So people shy away from such leaps. The computer hardware industry, for instance, is less interested in a revolutionary new paradigm for microprocessors than in a CPU that runs faster and cooler. Pharmaceutical companies aren't looking for a new understanding of biology; they want to use the current one to develop new drugs according to what they know and understand. That's not to say a revolutionary new idea wouldn't be welcome *once proven*, but it does mean that most of the time and effort people put into research and development is of the "gradual extension" sort.

With that in mind, here's an interesting thought: the next big transcendent invention that's going to revolutionize your life has probably already been discovered. We just haven't figured out what it's *for* yet.

Comment: This question is both broad and arguably off topic.  Please help new users improve questions before posting.